# Magento 1 License

Tags: magento-1.9

Now that Magento 1 has reached end of life, can I take Magento 1 source code and use it as the basis for closed-source software (not an e-commerce, but rebrand it to be an ERP or a CRM), creating my custom modules and distributing all the new rebranded tool as closed-source software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Magento 1 has reached end of life, it is no longer supported by the official Magento team, which means that there will be no security patches or updates to the code. However, Magento 1 is still subject to copyright law, and its source code is licensed under the Open Software License (OSL) version 3.0.

The OSL is a copyleft license, which means that if you modify or distribute the Magento 1 source code, any derivative work must also be licensed under the OSL and be made available as open source. Therefore, if you take the Magento 1 source code and modify it to create closed-source software, you would be violating the terms of the license and infringing on Magento's copyright.

if you want to create closed-source software based on Magento 1, you would need to obtain a separate license from Magento, which would allow you to modify the source code and distribute the resulting software as closed-source.

Comment: Thank you @Rejith. I know some companies doing exactly the opposite. They have been using Magento 1 and distributed modified copies as closed-source rebranded software. I know they are doing that still now. Do you think it is ok to inform Magento about that? How can I reach the Magento team to report those violations?